# document.URL Matching in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url which looks like this 
https://test.high.com/people/11111111-name-firstname-_custa/deals/new

Now i need to match document.URL 
if im on that Page if so i will alert a message.

The important part is /deals/new

How can i match that in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var regex = new RegExp("/deals/new$");
if(document.URL.match(regex))
  alert("yeah");
```

Answer (score 2):

A Regex matching any string ending with `"/deals/new"` is

```
"/deals/new$"
```

If you need your link to only contain `/deals/new`, try

```
"/deals/new(/|$)"
```

Comment: don't forget escaping: `/\/deals\/new$/`

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean that you want access to the documents url from javascript?

That is done via the documents `location` property.
Try `document.location.href` or only `location.href`.